# jQuery DataTable rendering applying only on one target at a time

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a `DataTable` which fills its data through an `ajax` call. I'm rendering two targets but only the second target is being rendered. Below is my code

```
columnDefs: [
  { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 1 },
  { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 2 },
  { responsivePriority: 3, targets: 3 },
  { responsivePriority: 7, targets: 4 },
  { responsivePriority: 4, targets: 5 },
  { responsivePriority: 5, targets: 6 },
  { responsivePriority: 6, targets: 7 },
  {
    'targets': 2,
    'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
       return type === 'display' && data.length > 10 ?
              data.substr(0, 10) + '…' :
              data;
  },
  'targets': 7,
  'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
    // Something here
  },
}],
```

Here only `targets : 7` is rendering but not `2`.

Comment: You just mess scopes up. Try to be careful with opening and closing curly brackets. If you disagree show the entire code.

Comment: I have just updated by whole columnDefs code. Please have a look.

Comment: Also if I move targets : 2 after targets: 7 it works for targets:2 but this time targets:7 does not render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close `}` for each target like below.

```
columnDefs: [

            { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 1 },
            { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 2 },
            { responsivePriority: 3, targets: 3 },
            { responsivePriority: 7, targets: 4 },
            { responsivePriority: 4, targets: 5 },
            { responsivePriority: 5, targets: 6 },
            { responsivePriority: 6, targets: 7 },
            { 'targets': 2,
              'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                 return type === 'display' && data.length > 10 ? data.substr(0,10) + '…' : data; }
           },
           { 'targets': 7,
             'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                //Something here
             }
           }
        ],
```